# ProgressBar crashed

Tags: java, progress-bar, jprogressbar

I am trying to use a JProgressBar, but my code is really slow and almost crash each time I run my application. At the beginning, the progress bar is set to indeterminate, then when you hit the button "Stop" (in my program, when the background task is done), the progress bar is set to determinate and start to fill quickly.

How can I improve the efficiency of this code ? I didn't find a lot of resources on indeterminate JProgressBar.

Here is my code :

```java
public class test extends JFrame { 

    static JFrame f; 
    static JProgressBar b; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f = new JFrame("ProgressBar demo"); 
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel p = new JPanel(); 
        b = new JProgressBar(); 
        b.setValue(0);   
        b.setStringPainted(true); 
        b.setIndeterminate(true);
        p.add(b); 
        f.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH); 
        JButton button = new JButton("stop");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                b.setIndeterminate(false);
                fill();
            }
            
        });
        f.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.setSize(500, 500); 
        f.setVisible(true); 
        //fill(); 
    }
          
            // function to increase progress 
    public static void fill() { 
        int i = 0; 
        try { 
            while (i <= 100) { 
                b.setValue(i + 10); 
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
                i += 20; 
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {} 
    } 

}
```

Comment: Well at this point the bar just makes 100 steps of 1s each. You might want to make the value of the bar dependent on some progress of your application instead.

Comment: @JakobF Unfortunately, I can't calculate how the application progress, that's why I am using an indeterminate progress bar..

Comment: But if you do not know the state of progress and have an indeterminate ProgressBar why do you want to manually set values for it? The Inderterminate progress bar ist just an infinite cyclic animation. As you can see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar#setProgress(int `setValue()` has no effect in your case.

Comment: I wanted to have an indeterminate progress bar until my app terminate, then switch to a determinate progress bar which fill really quickly to show that it's done. Maybe the undeterminate only is better, but it looks like there is now other way to stop it than switch to determinate mode (according to only example I found on the net)

Comment: You should read the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) section of the Oracle Swing Tutorial. It will tell you about the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Your GUI should be running in this thread. Right now, you are running everything in your main thread, which is why you are blocking your GUI when doing other stuff (such as `fill()`). Read through the [How to Use Progress Bars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) section and then check out the linked `ProgressBarDemo.java` for a working example.

Comment: Also, you should stick to the java naming conventions (class names should start uppercase). Also also, there is no need to `extend JFrame` if you then define a default `JFrame` variable.

Comment: Why do you say this almost crashes?